# Carregar table via AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-core

Estou tentando carregar os dados de uma tabela, via ajax, desta forma:

```
function buscaFornecedores(id) {
    var url = "/Produto/BuscaFornecedor";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: id},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#tabelaf").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

E aqui é como está no controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult BuscaFornecedor(int id)
    {
        var fornecedor_produto = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Where(p => p.ProdutoID == id).ToList();

        return Json(new { Resultado = fornecedor_produto });
    }
```

Porém ele aparece em branco, o que está faltando no código ?

Edit:
O console log aparece desta forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código da table:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tabelaf">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fornecedores</th>
                            <th style="text-align:right"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAdd" title="Adicionar Novo Fornecedor" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosFornecedores)
                        {
                            <tr class="tr">
                                <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <a class="link-excluir" href="#" data-id="@item.Id" title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Tentei utilizar, fazendo desta forma:

```
 public JsonResult BuscaFornecedor(int id)
{
    var fornecedor_produto = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Where(p => p.ProdutoID == id).ToList();

    return Json(new { Resultado = fornecedor_produto });
}
```

Porém também não deu certo. No MVC comum utilizaria JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, porém no MVC Core não é possível.

**EDIT:**

Tentei passando desta forma também, porém continua o mesmo problema:

```
public ActionResult BuscaFornecedor(int id)
    {
        var fornecedor_produto = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Where(p => p.ProdutoID == id).ToList();

        return new JsonResult(new { Resultado = fornecedor_produto });
    }
```

Comment: `$("#tabelaf").html(data.resultado);`?

Comment: Continua vindo em branco

Comment: O seu (fornecedor_produto) está sendo populado? Caso sim use:  return Json(fornecedor_produto , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: coloque um `console.log(data)` dentro da função `success` para ver no console do navegador o dado retornado e como está a estrutura das informações para você poder acessar.

Comment: @NetinhoSantos não deu certo.

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães fiz o console.log, e coloquei a imagem com os dados retornado na pergunta.

Comment: Qual é exatamente o seu problema.? Ao vê o Edit da sua pergunta os dados estão sendo retornado no ajax.

Comment: nessa `#tabelaf` você quer retornar uma table?

Comment: Coloquei o código da tabela para que vocês possam entender. Isso @Barbetta quero retornar para ela os dados do ajax.

Comment: Primeiro, se você olhar seu JSON, vai ver que está vindo nulo em vários campos.
Segundo, ou você usa Razor, ou Ajax na sua tabela, as duas coisas vai ter overhead.
Terceiro, você está recebendo json e não html, use um for no javascript para que você printe uma linha da tabela para cada item do json recebido.

Comment: Eu só preciso dos dados fornecedor id e produto id. os outros campos irão ser retirados, creio que o problema não é este

Comment: @GustavoSantos você tem algum exemplo para me auxiliar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que você está retornando um `Json` e não o html da tabela.

Mude seu código da seguinte forma:

```
function buscaFornecedores(id) {
    var url = "/Produto/BuscaFornecedor";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: id},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#tabelaf").html(data).promise().done(function () {
                $(".modal").modal('show');
            });
        }
    });
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BuscaFornecedor(int id)
{
    var fornecedor_produto = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Where(p => p.ProdutoID == id).ToList();

    return PartialView("_SuaPartialView", fornecedor_produto);
}
```

Agora irá retornar o `html` com as informações

Uma alternativa com menos código para o carregar as informações é fazer assim:

```
function buscaFornecedores(id) {
    $("#tabelaf").load("/Produto/BuscaFornecedor/" + id, function(){
        $(".modal").modal('show');
    });     
}
```

Comment: Eu só não entendi a parte do PartialView @Barbetta, como vou vincular a tabela a partialview ?

Comment: Na parte que você adicionou o código da tabela aquilo deveria ser uma `PartialView`, ela não tem nada de diferente de uma `View`, o que muda é que ao retornar ela sua aplicação não irá passar pelo `ViewStart`. Nessa sua `View` ela tem um model, na parte do `PartialView("_SuaPartialView", fornecedor_produto);` você está indicando o nome dessa `View` e do lado o model do retorno

Comment: No `_SuaPartialView` mude o nome para o nome do arquivo `cshtml` que você deseja carregar, é importante que o modelo passado ao lado seja o `mesmo` que a View recebe

Comment: este código está dentro de um modal, não estou sabendo lidar com PartialView, estou utilizando mvc core.

Comment: Editei a resposta, coloquei para após carregar as informações ele abrir o modal

Comment: no mvc comum, funciona, eu fiz o teste, porém não consigo fazer funcionar no mvc core. :(